# How do I change language in Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare from Russian to English?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I live in a Middle Asian Country, I can't find any English version of the game, so I bought the game and installed it. Now the language is all in Russian and unfortunately I don't understand Russian. How can I change it to English?

Answer (score 6):

**You cant change your games language directly.** Been there and tried that. It too messy work and at the end there were so many errors. Also, you need to get the english audios from somewhere.. Also some of the language is bind to the .iwd files (core.)

If you have bought the russian game (half the price compared to english.) Then there is a way to get it into english:

1. First backup your profile
2. Uninstall the russian version
3. "Borrow" your "friends" english version and install it
4. Use your own legimate keys on the install.
5. Install your backedup profile to your fresh english game

I'm the owner of [IYFGN](http://www.iyfgaming.com). All my members have bought the russian "key" legitimately and used it with the english version.

Answer (score 2):

Try [setting](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8487-WSCN-4121) your Steam client language

Comment: This does not work, that's why the question was asked. It still does not work in 2023.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the English version instead. because the "zone" folder may differ depending on what language pack/version you have installed.